# AllowedContent configuraion for email templates

Tags: ckeditor

Does any one created have a `allowedContent` options file that can be used for the editor that generates pretty good formatted HTML for emails? I am using ckEditor 4.1.2

So far I have this but I am struggling with displaying the font face, family and size dropdown lists. At the moment my dropdowns do not appear.

```
   config.allowedContent =
      'p;' +
      'sup strike blockquote code kbd samp var del ins cite q b i u strike ul ol li hr caption; ' +
      'img[!src,alt,align,width,height]; font[!face]; font[!family]; font[!color]; font[!size]; font{!background-color}; a[!href]; a[!name]; ' +
      'table tbody tr td th[*]{*}(*);';
```

Also I am not 100% sure what a good config for `allowedContent` would look like for an WYSIWYG editor that works for emails.

Comment: Have you seen this sample? http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/htmlwriter/outputhtml.html

Comment: Thanks, also have found this and this seems to be what I am after, http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/datafiltering.html (this is for V4.1 onwards)